# Get posts from a taxonomy inside a post as links but not get the current post as link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

**The Explanation**

I have Custom Post Type called **Books**, with a Taxonomy called **book_series**,
I want to get all the other posts under this series as links Book Title but the current book as not a link.

**More Explanation:**

I have a `single-books.php` page to show the book details including the book series as links (List of book titles from the same Series) so the user can see and (click the link) on the other books in this series, also the current book is listed but as text not as a link.

**A picture of clearing Things:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
global $post;
$current_book_id = $post->ID;

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('Books'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'category_name' => 'book_series',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php 
        //if current post; just display the name
        if (the_ID() == $current_book_id) { ?>
            <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php } 
        //display name with the hyper link.
        else { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php }
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; // End of the loop.
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Didn't Worked for me!, Hope anyone else has another solution.